# AngularJS destroy HTML DOM and cause troubles to Esri map

Tags: angularjs, dojo, esri

We have a web app developed by AngularJS v1.4.12, and the home page has a large Esri map shown, however, when leave the map page and then get back later (by AngularJS routing), we noticed that the HTML DOM of the previous map page was destroyed and a new copy was generated, but the Esri map object is still tied to the old DOM and that cause troubles, so finally we decided to always run the code which is used to render the Esri map when enter the map page, but probably because our limited experience on Esri and Dojo, we can only run that code in a setTimeout callback to make sure the DOM get ready, but this cause lots of dependencies and new problems.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to force AngularJS not to destroy the HTML DOM when leave a page (e.g. persist it in a cache managed by AngularJS and reuse it later)?
2. If #1 is impossible, then any other approach to elegantly and efficiently re-generate the Esri map?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map library? The sites for ArcGIS [v4.x examples](http://esri.github.io/angular-esri-map/#/examples/) and [v3.x examples](https://arcgis.github.io/angular-esri-map-site-v1/#/examples) both use the angular router and neither has the problems you describe above.

The source code for those sites are available in that repository:

- ArcGIS API v4.x: https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map/tree/master/site
- ArcGIS API v3.x: https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map/tree/v1.x/site